# JQUERY Autcomplete while typing with remote data

Tags: jquery

I want use the below code but using remote data, instead of use " tags"  variable I want to use a URL for get data through a Rest API.

```
var tags = ["c++", "java", "php", "coldfusion", "javascript", "asp", "ruby"];
$("#field").autocomplete({
  source: function(request, response) {
    var matcher = new RegExp("^" + $.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex(request.term), "i");
    response($.grep(tags, function(item) {
      return matcher.test(item);
    }));
  },
  disabled: true,
});
```

similar to this

```
$("#rfc_cta_ord").autocomplete({
    source:'/erp_invoice/get_all_RFC_bank_json'
});
```

Comment: what is the `URL` of the `API` where you want to load the list from?

Comment: This "/erp_invoice/get_all_RFC_bank_json" but just works in local

Comment: What about this [documentation example](https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#remote-jsonp) (click on "view source" link)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `source` option can be used in three variations

> - Array
> - String
> - Function (callback)

I would prefer using the third one, a callback provides the most flexibility and can be used to connect any data source to Autocomplete, including JSONP. The callback gets two arguments:

> - request
> - response

you can replace the following code chunk with your existing function to load the list from the `API` you desire

```
source:function(request, response) {
      jQuery.getJSON(
        "YOUR_API_URL?callback=?&q=" + request.term,
        function(data) {
          response(data);
        }
      );
    },
```